# Need test for asynchronous I/O

Tags: c, asynchronous, fortran, lustre

I am new to asynchronous I/O.  I am trying to get it to work in C and Fortran codes on a Linux system.  Based on what I can find out about the platform's somewhat outdated Lustre file system, the various `aio` routines are supported, after a fashion, but it is not clear that they can execute in true asynchronous fashion.  Is there some simple code to test whether true asynchronous I/O is occurring in the execution of a code?